# Polarization in dielectric matter - "feedback" effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, polarization

I'm concerned about the following scenario of polarization in a perfect dielectric:

When a material is exposed to an electric field it develops polarization proportional to the electric field.

From here, books say that you can integrate the small polarization dipole moments in the material to find their combined effect on the potential of a point outside the material.

This makes sense to me, but I'm concerned that the various dipole moments would alter the electric field in the material (which in fact they do) and thereby alter the dipole moments we started with.

For example, it is said that a slab of material exposed to an E field due north, will polarize such that it'd produce E fields due south (inside the slab itself).
But these consequent E fields would surely alter the polarization density, such that it's not the same as the polarization density with only the external field.

So it appears that the external field produced by a dielectric in an applied constant E field may not be the simple sum of the applied E field + (the combined effects of the induced dipole moments, as solely induced by the applied field)?

Wouldn't it be the case, the actual final dipole moments won't match those produced by the applied external field, because these induced dipole moments (by the applied external field) would then further alter the E field in the material, thereby altering polarization of the material? (with the final polarization equilibrium being different than the dipole moments as simply resulting of the applied external field).

Comment: The proportionality of the polarization is *after* all the transient buildup you have described will have taken place. It is assumed that the transients are so much faster than anything we do outside that it is nearly instantaneous. Whether the steady, that is, after the transients polarization  is really proportional to the external field and also to the internal macroscopic average field is an experimental fact for most dielectrics over a wide range of field intensities but it is not necessarily true. In fact, some ceramic materials are strongly nonlinear, e.g., $BaTiO_3$ and its relatives.

Comment: Thanks; I'm just concerned that the external applied field is not the only factor to determine polarization, even when all transients stabilize. There is some additional "negative feedback" E field that the polarization itself produces, and it has to be accounted for in the final equilibrium. (The image in the answer below shows the kind of a negative feedback E field I'm thinking about.)

Answer (score 1):

What you describe certainly happens. You will find it described in many texts, in the treatment of fields in macroscopic media. Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics" [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Electrodynamics_(book))] shows it in Chapt. 4 like this:

[image: Jackson]

It should be mentioned that this feedback mechanism can also give you a non-zero field without any external field, like ferro-electric materials (or ferro-magnetic, if we talk about magnetic instead of electric fields). This would of course require a positive feedback. But as the drawing shows, in a classical treatment it seems to be negative when described by the accumulated boundary charges and that would only reduce the field.

To see cases with positive feedback you would need to look very carefully at the microscopic charges that actually create the polarization and you need a quantum mechanical treatment to do that correctly. The Pauli exclusion principle is needed for the [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism#Explanation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds like the final polarization will be smaller then that without feedback. Maybe the equilibrium clearing condition is: E0 + E(negative feedback) relates to P(final), and P(final) is such as to produce exactly E(negative feedback). This P(final) is smaller than P from E0 alone. It reminds me of op amp negative feedback (where the output returns to the input and there is some clearing equilibrium).